# how to create favourite system in laravel with relations with multi model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

i create favourites,but i have a problem. favourites migration

```
$table->integer('user_id');
$table->integer('favouriteable_id');
$table->string('favouriteable_type');
```

Favourite.php

```
protected $fillable = ['user_id'];
public function favouriteable()
{
 return $this->morphTo();
}
```

Post.php

```
    public function favourite()
    {
        return $this->morphOne(Favourite::class, 'favouriteable');
    }
    public function checkFavourites()
    {
            return $this->favourite->count() && auth()->user()->id == $this->favourite->user_id;
    }
```

view file

```
@auth
                    <form action="{{route('add-favorites', $data->id)}}" method="post">
                        @csrf
                        <button
                            class="project like_Heart Button_Search lp-glass lp-rounded-min lp-cu text-bold ho">
                            <i class="fa-duotone fa-circle-heart lp-lg favorite @if($data->checkFavourites()) active @endif"></i>
                        </button>
                    </form>
                @else
                    <a href="/login">
                        <button class="project like_Heart Button_Search lp-glass lp-rounded-min lp-cu text-bold ho">
                            <i class="fa-duotone fa-circle-heart lp-lg favorite"></i>
                        </button>
                    </a>
                @endif
```

it,s work but problem this here.If a post is added to the favorites by the user, there is no problem and it works, otherwise I get this error

```
Attempt to read property "user_id" on null
```

Comment: What `dd($this->favourite)` in `checkFavourites` is showing?

Comment: In the post that is added to the favorites, it shows an object of the interested model. In the posts that are not added to the favorites, it returns the null value.

Comment: Okay, alright !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attempt to read property "user_id" on null because there is no $this-> favorite record. It's returning null, in this case.

```
$this->favourite === null
```

Comment: this work but only check first record for user,For example, the user with ID 1 adds this post to the favorites and it works, but when the user with ID 2 adds the same post to the favorites, he can not check if the second user does this. Has done or not

Answer (score 0):

### In your Post.php Model

```
public function checkFavourites()
    {
        if($this->favourite) {
            return $this->favourite->count() && auth()->user()->id == $this->favourite->user_id;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The problem is still there, do you think this problem is not due to relationships? If so, how should I write it, assuming that this table is supposed to be connected to several models?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).